# selecting OpenGL range elements GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER

Tags: c++, opengl

i have interleaved array as GL_ARRAY_BUFFER  (Vertex|Normals|Textures) in vbo 1, there are some textures to be applied on them.

i have vector array contain start and end of the face where texture is to be applied
ie. 
face 50 to 3000 Apply texture 1
face 3001 to 5000 Apply texture 2

How can i build GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER index Array for every texture keeping same ARRAY_BUFFER?

Comment: Why don't you just call `glDrawArrays( ? , 50, 3000);` then switch the texture and then `glDrawArrays( ? , 3001, 5000);`?

Comment: can i map texcoord and normals also

Comment: An index buffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER) won't help you with that. It only specifies in what order vertices are rendered.

Comment: i will have some test with glDrawArrays on separate arrays coz i dont think it will work with interleaved array

Comment: It works with interleaved arrays. You have to bind them properly though (with `glVertexAttribPointer()`).

Comment: thanks that would even allow me to get rid of DrawRangedElement from my code

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
// fill "indices" as needed
    // Generate a buffer for the indices
GLuint elementbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &elementbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: i need to do same for multiple textures keeping interleaved Array buffer same